# iPhone remove substring from string

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring

Hi I have a string like that

```
NSString *str=@"1,2,3,4";
```

I have to remove any character from it **dynamically**. For example, `@"3,"`.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
NSString *str=@"1,2,3,4";
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"3," withString:@""];
```

That will remove ALL occurrences of @"3," in `str`.

If you want to remove only the first occurrence of @"3,":

```
NSString* str = @"1,2,3,4";
NSRange replaceRange = [str rangeOfString:@"3,"];
if (replaceRange.location != NSNotFound){
    NSString* result = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:replaceRange withString:@""];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"3," withString:@""];

Comment: This will only work if you know that the item to be removed is part-way through the list. For example, if number 4 was to be removed, you would have to know that it is at the end of the list and that there is no trailing comma so you replace "4" with "" rather than "4,".

Comment: @NickBull Of course, the question is about a way of removing 'any character'. So you know the character.

Comment: But you are removing 'any characterS'.

Comment: @NickBull I just put the comma, ',', because it's in the question. This method works for any substring wherever it is.

Comment: @sonxurxo what if the number is till 14 and he wants to remove 3? you can assume the results.. 14 will be converted to 114

Comment: @Avengers He is talking about characters, not numbers. I posted a method to remove just the first character/substring, or all the occurrences of a character/substring. Don't understand where's the problem with that

Comment: @AvengersI think you are misunderstanding things. We are talking about chars and strings, not numbers. It's the same for @"1,2,3,4" that for @"bla,ble bli bla blahhhh"

Comment: @user1138416 If you consider that the answer solves your problem, please mark it as the answer of your questions, so that others can reach it.

Answer (score 6):

```
  NSString *str=@"1,2,3,4";
  int numberToRemove = 4;

 str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numberToRemove] withString:@""];
 str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@",," withString:@","];
```

This will help.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, if anyone will help!

```
NSString *newStr = @"";
    newStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"3," withString:@""];
```

Comment: Please, provide an explanation about your answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer